# Grails MissingPropertyException

Tags: grails, groovy, properties, runtime-error

I've been getting a strange error that has had me hung up all morning. I have a Grails application with a Person class that looks like this:

```
class Person {
        String id
    Date   lastUpdated
    String note
    String lastName
    String firstName
    String middleName
    String facility
    ...
}
```

In my controller, I have a closure to obtain the model:

```
def personDetail = {
    Person person = new Person()
    ...
    List<Person> personSearchList = session.getAttribute("searchResults")
    Person selectedSearchPerson = selectedSearchPersonList.find { it.id == selectedID }
    person.firstName = selectedSearchPerson.firstName
    person.lastName = selectedSearchPerson.lastName
    person.middleName = selectedSearchPerson.middleName
    person.facility = selectedSearchPerson.facility
    ...
    return [person:person]
}
```

Now, this code was working fine yesterday. This morning however, without making any modifications (I have even tried reverting to older svn submissions) I am getting the following error when I click the g:link to display the detailController gsp:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: facility for class: org.icf.Person
at org.bjc.icf.DetailController$_closure3.doCall(DetailController.groovy:33)
at org.bjc.icf.DetailController$_closure3.doCall(DetailController.groovy)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I've tried looking up a solution to what might be causing this error online but I can't seem to find anything. Does anyone have any idea why I might all of a sudden be getting MissingPropertyExceptions on previously working code (and yes, I have checked to make sure the property is still in the class).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try running `grails clean` - sometimes incremental compilation fails so forcing a full compile will often make weird issues like this go away.

Comment: Thanks Burt. I had tried cleaning several times before (including restarting my computer!) but it didn't work. What did wind up working was running your suggestion from command line (instead of the STS IDE).

Comment: Right - cleaning the project in STS or another IDE just clears its compiled classes, but they're not the same as the ones Grails compiles for run-app. So when run-app acts funky, run `grails clean` and when the IDE is funky, clean the project.